# How to add Sikuli's dll files to a runnable jar file

Tags: java, testing, automated-tests, sikuli

I have used Sikuli java .jar to test a website, now I need to make a runnable .jar file and give it to my costumer, but I do not know how to add Sikuli's dll files to the jar in a way that it does not change any thing on the costumer's computer. I am using Eclipse LUNA.

Answer (score 0):

To add sikuli libraries with your java program's jar , you should add sikuli java.jar into build path path of your java project in the eclipse platform.

then export your project. It will add sikuli lib into your exported jar.